# How to remove any xml property from java code in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-xml

I have set these properties of an `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image_view"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />
```

Now from Java code, I want to remove `scaleType` property form this image view. I dont want any scale type to be on this ImageView.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Try to remove android:scaleType="centerCrop" and recheck?

Comment: Did you check [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setScaleType(android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType))?

Comment: Do you mean, you want the original intent of the ImageView to have a scaleType but then you would like to change it at runtime?

Comment: I want to remove this `scaleType` property. I know i can add different properties to scaleType from code, but i dont want to apply any scaleType to this image

Comment: Use imageViewObject.setScaleType(null);

Comment: @ArbazRizvi: thanks let me try this

Comment: use .setScaleType method for changing scaleType at runtime, if you want to remove scaleType pass null to .setScaleType method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If You Not Set Any Scale Type Then For Image View Default Scale Type is `FIT_CENTER`

```
//So to remove other scale types and set to default use
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

Comment: Thanks, let me try this

Answer (score 1):

This is how you set or change the Image View scale type at runtime from within Java:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER);
```

You can refer to this [documentation page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) for the possible ScaleType options.

Comment: Thanks, I want to remove this `scaleType` property. By this I can add different properties to scaleType from code, but i dont;t  want to apply any scaleType to this image

Comment: @Kirmani88 the default is FIT_CENTER so if you set it to that, it would be as if you didn't specify any ScaleType at all in the XML to begin with

Comment: you can't remove scale type or you can't set to null. Check my answer. You have to set it to default FIT_CENTER.